# Add and save data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asprepeater

This is my table in SQL Server:

```
Create table SubTypes
(
    IDSub int primary key identity(1,1),
    Offerstype varchar(255) not null,
    CostOffers varchar(25) not null
);
```

Code in asp.net

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>ALL Offers</legend>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Offers" runat="server" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Offers type</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("IDSub")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Offerstype")%></td><--error-->
                <td><%#Eval("CostOffers")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("delete from SubTypes where IDSub=@IDSub;")%></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</fieldset>
```

C#

```
SportsCenterEntities db = new SportsCenterEntities();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        Offers_DataBinding();
    }
}

public void Offers_DataBinding()
{
    Offers.DataSource = db.SubTypes.ToList();
    Offers.DataBind();
}
```

Error

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SubType_084D6F49655DAD7C286182B0A82194429DD9DDEC3EA06D3CB3ED078CA68E2371' does not contain a property with the name 'SubType'.

[image]

Comment: Is 'SportsCenterEntities()' an object you create with attributes? It looks to me like you're using that to hold results from the database, but you haven't created the attribute on that object. Can you show us that section of your code?

Comment: yes i think that, how i can create this attribute?

Comment: What is this: `<td><%#Eval("delete from SubTypes where IDSub=@IDSub;")%></td>`? I dont think we have `Eval(sql command)`... And your itemtemplate is not true. you mustn't have `</table>` in item template, because it will repeat on each row.

Comment: i want to add a option "delete" in table.. i know isn't true.. 
</table>.... I know that but it gives an error when executing the program

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<asp:Repeater ID="Offers" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Delete"> >
    <HeaderTemplate>            
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Offers type</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("IDSub")%></td>
            <td><%#Eval("Offerstype")%></td><--error-->
            <td><%#Eval("CostOffers")%></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" IDSub='<%#Eval("IDSub")%>' Text="Delete"/></td>
        </tr>            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

And in code behind catch the event sent from row:

```
protected void Delete(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Button clickedDeleteButton= (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnDelete"); 
            int idSub = int.Parse(clickedDeleteButton.Attributes["IDSub"]);
            // Here Delete codes by id...
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives the same mistake

Comment: Then the problem is some where else, because we have not `SubType` any more. the error **does not contain a property with the name 'SubType'** ....

Comment: Previous name of  Offerstype is "SubType"... I renamed to  understand Required

Comment: Is the name in database also set to 'SubType' ? When yo use `Eval` the name must be exactly same as data base column. This error says you have bound a column that not exists.

Comment: SubType is Column in the table "SubTypes"

Comment: Debug your code, See the `Offers.DataSource` and check the fields have name exactly same as the bound fields names.